# How to get raw bluetooth data with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, pybluez

I have been looking all over the internet, and I haven't been able to figure out how to read incoming bluetooth data. I have a mouse I would like to get signals from currently, and I am planning on sending data between two computers at some point, but I current just want to be able to read the incoming data from a device I choose.

I have tried numerous different code examples, but for some reason an oddly high amount of them seem to be in Python 2.7, and *just about everything else says to `import bluetooth`, which gives a `ModuleNotFoundError` and cant be found by pip*. I have tried installing things like `PyBluez` and using `from network import Bluetooth` (`network.Bluetooth` doesnt exist) but none of it works.

I simply want to know how to *read incoming bluetooth data from a specific device with python 3*.

EDIT: I am using windows.

Comment: What operating system is this on? Linux? Windows?

Comment: @ukBaz Windows. Ill add that to the question.

Comment: It's not that easy, especially on Windows.  This is like asking for "raw USB data" for a USB mouse.  If you have a Bluetooth mouse, it's going to recognized as a mouse.  Windows will load a HID driver, and the raw data is not available.  There are lots of generic Bluetooth devices you CAN attach to.

Comment: Like I know I can get bluetooth data for other stuff, but I cant point the script to a mouse mac address like I would for any other device and get data from it?